# Sending a POST Request from a PUG FORM - Can't send data

Tags: node.js, express

Pug layout:

```
html(lang='en')
block login
    form(id="login" action="/users" method="post")
        input(type="text", name="username", value="", placeholder="Username")
        br
        input(type="password", name="password", value="", placeholder="Password")
        br
        input(type="submit" value="Connect")
```

And my JS code for the post:

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const user = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    });

    user.save()
    .then(data => {
        res.json(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.json({message: err})
    })

});
```

Can't seem to think on how to send the data from the form to the actual post request. It seems like it sends the request but with no information as I get:

`` {"message":{"errors":{"username":{"name":"ValidatorError","message":"Path `username` is required.","properties":{"message":"Path `username` is required." ``

Frustrated that I can make the requests in Postman but having a hard time implementing the requests into my app.

Answer (score 3):

Alright apparently my only problem was that I didn't use

```
router.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  }))
```

Quite frustrating.

Comment: I had router.use(express.json()); which worked when testing with curl, but this fixed my form. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue and indeed view engines can't send post requests unless you have

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

I already changed part of my code to use query perams instead of post because of this.

Comment: Hi, this code is already contained in the previuos answer